# Docker root error when starting Cassandra with a script

Tags: docker, cassandra, root

I'm trying to launch Cassandra in a Docker.

if I end my Dockerfile with

```
CMD["cassandra", "-f"]
```

it starts with no problem. But when I do it using a script:

```
COPY ./launch_cassandra.sh /tmp/cassandra/launch_cassandra.sh
CMD["sh", "/tmp/cassandra/launch_cassandra.sh"]
```

with `launch_cassandra.sh` containing only :

```
cassandra -f
```

I get the following error :

> Running Cassandra as root user or group is not recommended - please
>   start Cassandra using a different system user.

Why aren't these equivalent ? Why is the script run as root ?

Comment: I'm not sure why it works if you run it without the script but you should set the user to cassandra. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user

Comment: You can get some inspiration for your Dockerfile from the github repo of the official Cassandra Docker image: https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra

Comment: Actually my Dockerfile extends the official one (using `FROM cassandra`), so the user is set to cassandra. But I just noticed that the entrypoint is a script called `docker-entrypoint.sh` that does 'special' stuff when the first argument is cassandra. So this code is executed when `cassandra` is in the CMD, but not when I launch the script : the difference might come from it, I'll have a look at this script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comments above, my Dockerfile extends the official one (using `FROM cassandra`), where an entrypoint script is used (`docker-entrypoint.sh`) to set a few variables.

So these were indeed set when the CMD contained `cassandra`, but not with the script : that's where the difference comes from.

Comment: How you resolved this issue ?

Comment: Very old question - but from what I remember, it worked after setting the same variables that were in the entrypoint script of the Cassandra image

Comment: Thanks for reply, I will try on it

Answer (score 0):

If you are extending the cassandra image you have a cassandra user created (names can differ, refer to the Dockerfile of the image you want, for instance https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra/blob/master/3.11/Dockerfile).
The only thing missing is to set the user on your Dockerfile eg.:

```
FROM cassandra:3.11.10
USER cassandra
CMD ["cassandra" "-f"]
```